# Improve web service performance using AxiomSoapMesageFactory - degradation of performance with large number of users

Tags: web-services, spring-ws, jboss6.x, axiom, saaj

We currently call SOAP web services which send back very big responses.

We use Spring-WS (using WebServiceTemplate), JAX-WS client while invoking the web services and the application is run on Jboss EAP 6.0.

We also use SaajSoapMessageFactory currently. I read from forums that AxiomSoapMessageFactory should be used rather than SaajSoapMessageFactory (http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/common.html) to improve reading performance.

I made the following modification:

Replaced

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"> 
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

by

```
 <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="payloadCaching" value="false"/>
    </bean>
```

This change worked fine as expected. But from a performance perspective, I am getting surprising results.

For a test with **50 users** concurrently accessing the web service (indirectly via a screen that in turn invokes the web service), the overall response time (moment the button is clicked to the moment the response from the web service is displayed back on the screen) reduced from ~ 27 secs to 22 secs -that's a good 5 second improvement over SaajSoapMessageFactory.

However, when I ran a **100 user** test, the response time increased by 2 secs and SaajSoapMessageFactory appears to be better in this case.

Can someone explain the reason for this difference in performance despite AxiomSoapMessageFactory using streaming and avoiding building tree??

Comment: Which StAX implementation are you using?

Comment: If you are referring to Marshaller/Unmarshaller, I use JaxB  (org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller) with Spring WebServiceTemplate

Comment: I just use the one below :                                     response = (ResponseType)webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request) and marshalling and unmarshalling is automatically taken care. Are you referring to using A StreamReader here ?